# Add orders made by unauthenticated customers to their accounts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the following code to attach orders made by visitors to their accounts after registration.

```php
function action_woocommerce_created_customer( $customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated ) {
    // Link past orders to this newly created customer
    wc_update_new_customer_past_orders( $customer_id );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'action_woocommerce_created_customer', 10, 3 );
```

It seems to work correctly, but I have another problem. If the customer registered on the website places an order without being authenticated, the order is not displayed in his account. How can I solve this problem? I looked everywhere to find a solution, but, unfortunately, I tried to modify the code, but an error appears (internal server error). I didn't find anything.Can you help me with a solution?

Thank you in advance!